# How to send emails using Laravel 5 scheduler

Tags: laravel-5

I have a controller method which sends an email and I want to execute it with a scheduler. Can I directly call a controller or do I have to write a command? If so please send me a sample code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$schedule->call('Your\NameSpace\SomeClass@method')->dailyAt('10:00');
```

Instead you can use hourly(), daily(), weekly() as well.

Documentation and a full list of frequency options you can find here:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options

Further information for usage you find here:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling#defining-schedules